# Absolute Value of Error Function

Tags: special-functions, absolute-value, error-function

Let $z=a+\mathrm{i} b$ and $erf(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{z}e^{-t^2}~dt$. We know
\begin{align*}
\overline{erf(z)}=erf(\overline{z}).
\end{align*}
What can we say about
\begin{align*}
\vert erf(z)\vert=???.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

From the [Wolfram fuunction site](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Erf/19/03/0001/) you get 
$$|\mathrm{erf}(a+ib)|
=\sqrt{\mathrm{erf}\left(a-a\sqrt{-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}\right)
\mathrm{erf}\left(a+a\sqrt{-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}\right)}
$$

Comment: Thanks. It is not much different from the basic definition.